# Is there a way to control the number of bytes read in Reactor Netty's TcpClient?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I am using TcpClient to connect to a simple TCP echo server. Messages consist of the message size in 4 bytes followed by the message itself. For instance, to send the message "hello", the server will expect "0005hello", and respond with "0005hello". 
When testing under load (approximately 300+ concurrent users), adjacent requests sometimes result in responses "piling up", e.g. sending "0004good" followed by "0003day" might result in the client receiving "0004good0003" followed by "day".

In a conventional, non-WebFlux-based TCP client, one would normally read the first 4 bytes from the socket into a buffer, determine the length of the message N, then read the following N bytes from the socket into a buffer, before returning the response. Is it possible to achieve such fine-grained control, perhaps by using TcpClient's underlying Channel?

I have also considered the approach of accumulating responses in some data structure (Queue, StringBuffer, etc.) and having a daemon parse the result, but this has not had the desired performance in practice.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding a handler of type `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` to the Connection:

```
TcpClient.create()
        .host(ADDRESS)
        .port(PORT)
        .doOnConnected((connection) -> {
            connection.addHandler("parseLengthFromFirstFourBytes", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(9999, 0, 4) {
                @Override
                protected long getUnadjustedFrameLength(ByteBuf buf, int offset, int length, ByteOrder order) {
                    ByteBuf lengthBuffer = buf.copy(0, 4);
                    byte[] messageLengthBytes = new byte[4];
                    lengthBuffer.readBytes(messageLengthBytes);
                    String messageLengthString = new String(messageLengthBytes);
                    return Long.parseLong(messageLengthString);
                }
            });
        })
        .connect()
        .subscribe();
```

This solves the issue with the caveat that responses still "pile up" (as described in the question) when the application is subjected to sufficient load.